# A web addin does not show in Outlook 2013 (Office 365)

Tags: outlook-addin, office365-apps, outlook-2013

Could someone please advise on a path to investigate an Outlook 2013 addin issue? We have a customer with many users still using Outlook 2013. Our addin works for most of them but for a few users Outlook just would not show our addin in the ribbon, even though it starts just fine in Office 365 OWA.

Are there specific versions of Outlook 2013 that support the web add-in technology whereas earlier ones don't?

In our manifest:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Thank you

Comment: I think the following article could help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/outlook/add-ins/troubleshoot-outlook-add-in-activation

Comment: I don't have access to the user's Outlook right now so it may take a while to get more info. Btw, the server is Office 365 so alot of what is suggested in the article is not applicable as the server is not a problem.

Comment: Is there a specific build number when Outlook 2013 started supporting web addins or all builds should support them?

Comment: Yes they should have a minimal specific build as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets. But it should work with version 1.1 with older versions, but you use 'defaultMinVersion' but docs state this should be 'MinVersion'. Maybe check this again?

Comment: Ferry, sorry I can't find the minimum specific 2013 build in that document. Can you point it out please? Thank you.

Comment: See the bottom note in that article. All builds support 1.1 through 1.2, but 1.3 and 1.4 support was added later with updates.

Comment: Our manifest specifies DefaultMinVersion="1.1" so then the addin should work in all builds, correct?